# Symfony2 form type entity expanded extra option

Tags: symfony

I have the following entity field in my form :

```
    ->add('cover_recto_color', 'entity', [
        'label' => 'printers_products.cover_recto_color.label',
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true,
        'class' => 'VeoprintVeoProductBundle:VeoColor',
        'property' => 'name',
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('vc')
                ->innerJoin('vc.rectoProducts', 'p')
                ->where('p.family = :family')
                ->setParameter('family', $this->_family)
                ;
        }
    ])
```

This field retrieve a set of data to display it using a list of checkbox. I would like to add another custom choice in this list, representing a NULL value in database but representing a concrete value for the application.

I tried to edit the choices in the `finishView` function :

```
public function finishView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    $new_choice = new ChoiceView(null, 'value', 'label');
    $view->children['cover_recto_color']->vars['choices'][] = $new_choice;
}
```

But it doesn't work. Same for the `buildView` function.

How can I do?

Comment: Create a [form type extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_form_type_extension.html) for `entity`. 

Add a new option (i.e. `custom_choice`) and use `buildView` to apply the option.

Comment: Thank you. A colleague oriented me this way too, I'll check.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't yet found the solution or just for others reading:

Ensure you have:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\View\ChoiceView;
```

and the:

```
public function finishView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    $new_choice = new ChoiceView(array(), '0', 'Your color');
    $view->children['cover_recto_color']->vars['choices'][] = $new_choice;
}
```

The '0' in the new ChoiceView is the value of the new option and the ?Your color' is the text of the option.

And that's all, you don't need anything else.

This worked for me.